# buttons generated programmatically crash app when clicked.

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol, sigabrt

I'm trying to generate buttons dynamically in an swift given an initial value, an array of size 8 will generate 8 buttons.

However, even though the code works, whenever i click on any of the generated buttons, the app immediately crashes with error code "thread 1 signal SIGABRT" and the console reads "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".

I am then pointed to the line containing "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" in AppDelegate.swift.

I have tried the suggestions seen in other similar questions, to no avail,  see code below

```
func generateButtons (){

    var numberOfVillains = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",  "8", "9", "10"]
    var buttonY: CGFloat = 126  // our Starting Offset, could be 0
    for number in numberOfVillains {
        let segmentController = UISegmentedControl()
        //let villainButton = UISegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 50, height: 30)){
        buttonY = buttonY + 40  // we are going to space these UIButtons 50px apart
        segmentController.frame = CGRect(x:160, y:buttonY, width: 100,height:  30)
        //segment frame size
        segmentController.insertSegment(withTitle: "Off", at: 0, animated: true)
        //inserting new segment at index 0
        segmentController.insertSegment(withTitle: "On", at: 1, animated: true)
        //inserting new segment at index 1
        segmentController.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        //setting the background color of the segment controller
        segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        //setting the segment which is initially selected
        segmentController.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("segment:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        //calling the selector method
        self.view.addSubview(segmentController)
        //adding the view as subview of the segment comntroller w.r.t. main view controller
    }

}

func buttonPressed(sender: UISegmentedControl!) {
    print("ButtonIsSelected")
}
```

Comment: Side note - A few style things here that I think would improve your code. You refer to these as buttons, but they're not. Your array is called `numberOfVillains` which is confusing because you'd expect that to be a number rather than an array of strings. Your segmented controls are named `segmentController`, rather than something slightly more correct/clear like `segmentedControl`. Improving your naming conventions will improve the readability and maintainability of your code. Your array can also be changed to a `let` constant if you're not actually mutating it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things need to look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  func generateButtons (){
    ...
  }

  @objc func buttonPressed(sender: UISegmentedControl!) {
    print("ButtonIsSelected")
  }

}
```

and NOT like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  func generateButtons (){
    ...
  }

}

@objc func buttonPressed(sender: UISegmentedControl!) {
  print("ButtonIsSelected")
}
```

Also, to silence the compiler warning, try changing the line:

```
segmentController.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonPressed:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

to:

```
segmentController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Comment: this is how things are currently set up in my Xcode, if you have time, you can try running it and if it works for you then it means the problem lies elsewhere in my code

Comment: @Riazbapoo Actually, that was the first thing I tried; cutting and pasting your code into a new project I made for the purpose.  Compiled and ran successfully after making some minor changes.  (I am still on Swift 2; you appear to be using Swift 3.)  Did you try making the change from `Selector()` to `#selector()` that I suggested?

Comment: could you provide an excerpt of code to show exactly what and how it has to be changed as i am getting red compiler errors when replacing the text with what you suggested

Comment: @Riazbapoo  Sure.  I've appended this to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

you're setting a target of Selector(("segment:")) on the buttons. But then the method you added to handle the click is called buttonPressed()

change Selector(("segment:")) to Selector("buttonPressed:") and that should fix the issue

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested, same thing happens

Comment: You may also need to annotate the function with  @objc func buttonPressed(sender: UISegmentedControl). This forces it to be exposed to the objective c runtime so that the UIControl can call it.

Is this code inside a view controller? Also if the object you're using is removed from memory after the buttons are created, you will also get a crash. View controllers won't be removed from memory while they are still on screen.

Comment: thank you for your responses, I've added the "@objc" and the problem  still persists, and yes, all of this code is contained inside UIViewController

Comment: Jeffrey Bergier's suggestion should have fixed the problem.  I would suggest that the questioner double-check the spelling and punctuation of `"buttonPressed:"` in the selector, making sure that the `:` has not been omitted.  Also, don't ignore the compiler warnings.

Comment: @inwit i thought so too, here is my updated code, '  func generateButtons (){
           segmentController.insertSegment(withTitle: "On", at: 1, animated: true)
           segmentController.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
           segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
           segmentController.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonPressed:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
           self.view.addSubview(segmentController)
       }
        
 
    }
    
    "@objc" func buttonPressed(sender: UISegmentedControl!) {
        print("ButtonIsSelected")
    }
'

Comment: @Riazbapoo The "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" message is just the last line of the error message in the console.  There should have been a stack dump as well, and before that a message like `...segment:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...` or some such.  You should take a closer look at the first few lines of the error message for more clues.

Comment: @inwit it says "2016-10-05 21:14:43.942 bahss[7856:2065953] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[bahss.ViewController buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe4dec04390'"

Comment: @Riazbapoo could it be the double parentheses around the selector? Right now its Selector(("mySelector:")). Perhaps it needs to be Selector("mySelector:")? Drawing at straws here :-/

Comment: @inwit it was initially single parentheses, thereafter the compiler gave a warning suggesting i change it to double parentheses

Comment: @Riazbapoo A few observations: 1. There shouldn't be quotation marks around the `@objc`. 2. You still have an extra pair of parentheses around `buttonPressed:`. 3. Most importantly, the `func buttonPressed(sender:...) {...}` definition must occur within the view controller's implementation, not outside of it.

Comment: @inwit 1. the parentheses around "objc" were only used in the comment section because stackoverflow thought i was mentioning another user. 2. app crashes whether there are double or single parentheses. 3. the buttonPressed function is already in the class body and not the function body

Comment: One last suggestion.  When compiling, you will likely have seen the warning message: `Use '#selector' instead of explicitly constructing a 'Selector'`.  So try replacing `Selector(("buttonPressed"))` with `#selector(buttonPressed(_:))`.  I regularly use the latter construction, if only to silence the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem, apparently the function you're referencing for the generated buttons need not contain ":" nor any parentheses if it does not take in any arguments, also , the correct format is

```
segmentController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonPressed), for: .valueChanged)
```

as opposed to

```
segmentController.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonPressed:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)'
```